# My wamp web server is unreachable by mobile phone

Tags: mobile, wamp

I installed an wamp web server on my laptop, at home. I can access it by wifi but not by mobile data.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Your server is only exposed to your local network. You need port forwarding and static ip to reach it from outside of your home network. Or use some tunneling tool like `ngrok` or `localtunnel` if you need a quick solution.

Comment: It is accessible from outside ( I have port forwarding and static ip) but only by wifi, not by mobile data.